# Display of image in show page

Tags: grails, gsp

I have option of photo upload in my `create.gsp` page. I'm able to see the uploaded photo in my create page and able to upload my photo in database, but cannot see that photo in my show page.

This is `create.gsp` page

```
<html>        
    <head>           
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />         
        <meta name="layout" content="billing-without-grid" />         
            <g:set var="entityName"         
        value="${message(code: 'skeletonBill.label', default: 'SkeletonBill')}" />            
        <title><g:message code="default.create.label"        
         args="[entityName]" /></title>           

        <script>      
            function showPhoto(imageFile) {        
             var fileReader = new FileReader();       
             var image = document.getElementById("uploadPhotoFile");       
             fileReader.onload = function(e) {          
            image.src = e.target.result;          
            }      
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(imageFile.files[0]);       
        }        
       </script>         
    </head>           
    <body>         
     <div class="body">          
     <div class="container-fluid">          
     <div class="row">          
     <div class="span6">         
         <img src="" name="uploadPhotoFile" id="uploadPhotoFile"            
                    height="200" width="160" />       
     <table style="width: 25%">        
     <tbody>       
     <tr class="prop">       
     <td valign="top" class="name"><label for="uploadPhoto"><g:message                        code="uploadInformation.uploadPhoto.label" default="Upload Photo" /></label></td>            
        <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: uploadInformationInstance,           field:    'uploadPhoto', 'errors')}">  
         <input type="file" id="uploadPhoto" name="uploadPhoto"         onchange="showPhoto(this)" />            
        </td>
        </tr>         
        </tbody>         
    </table>         
    </div>         
        </div>         
        </div>    
    </div>        
  </body>           
</html> '
```

Domain class that I created

```
class UploadInformation {       
     static constraints = {     
         uploadPhoto(nullable:true, maxSize: 16384 /* 16K */)       
     }      
     byte[] uploadPhoto        
     static transients = ["uploadPhoto"]         
     static mapping = {      
         uploadPhoto column:"uploadPhoto",sqlType: "blob"         
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anuj.

The problem I see after quick look at your code is:

```
static transients = ["uploadPhoto"]
```

***UploadPhoto*** will not be saved to database because it's declarated as transient.

See more details [transient properties](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html)

Comment: But my question is still unanswred. I want to display the image in my show.gsp page though it is in the form of blob in database.

Comment: thanx for the help Mr. Cat. It is working now.Photo is geting saved into thae database. 
My second question is that how to display the same image in show.gsp page though the photo is saved in database as in blog

Comment: Sure. Take a look at http://grails.org/Simple+Avatar+Uploader. Here you can find that avatar is also saved as blob (byte[] avatar). Take a look and you find here all you need